# dividing quatity INT value into unique separate rows for each item

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project where we are selling tickets. How do I create multiple rows from a quantity value. Currently it looks like this

```
line_item_id | order_id | product_id | quantity
------------------------------------------------
      1      |     1    |      6     |    5
------------------------------------------------
```

I wish for my end result to look like this into a separate table

```
ticket_id    | customer_id | product_id | quantity
------------------------------------------------
      1      |     2       |      6     |    1
------------------------------------------------
      2      |     2       |      6     |    1
------------------------------------------------
      3      |     2       |      6     |    1
------------------------------------------------
      4      |     2       |      6     |    1
------------------------------------------------
      5      |     2       |      6     |    1
------------------------------------------------
```

I am using a stored procedure but every time I call it it does what I want but it also duplicates the previous data into the table as well as adding the new tickets.

Also here is the stored procedure. Maybe I'm doing something wrong

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proc_item_import`()
BEGIN
    # Declare variables to read records from the cursor
    DECLARE parent_id_val INT(10) UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE item_type_val VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE quantity_val INT(11);

    # Declare variables for cursor and loop control
    DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE item_qty INT DEFAULT 0;

    # Declare the cursor
    DECLARE item_cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT oi.MerchID, m.MerchName, oi.quantity FROM orders o
            JOIN order_items oi ON o.id = oi.order_id
            JOIN merchandise m ON m.MerchID = oi.MerchID
                WHERE o.customer_id = 2 AND
                MerchCatID = '7' OR MerchCatID = '8';

    # Declare handlers for exceptions
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET no_more_rows = TRUE;

    # Open the cursor and loop through results
    OPEN item_cur;

    input_loop: LOOP

        FETCH item_cur
        INTO parent_id_val, item_type_val, quantity_val;

        # Break out of the loop if there were no records or all have been processed
        IF no_more_rows THEN
            CLOSE item_cur;
            LEAVE input_loop;
        END IF;

        SET item_qty = 0;

        qty_loop: LOOP

            INSERT INTO items_new
                (itemID, itemDesc)
            SELECT
                parent_id_val, item_type_val;

            SET item_qty = item_qty + 1;

            IF item_qty >= quantity_val THEN
                LEAVE qty_loop;
            END IF;

        END LOOP qty_loop;

    END LOOP input_loop;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Simple question - If you run the SELECT statement from your cursor, do you get back `order_items` rows that you've already generated `items_new` rows for? Then, you need some way to record which `order_items` rows have already been processed. On a related note - wouldn't you want something to tie an `items_new` row back to the `order_items` it came from>

Comment: the `items_new` table would actually be a `ticket_assignment` table in which i would only need the `customerID` and the `merchID` which i can get. the problem is the stored procedure will duplicate all the old data as well as the new data. @RDFozz

Answer (score 0):

To prevent all existing `order_items` rows for being added to `items_new`, you have to exclude rows that have already been processed from the cursor.

There are several ways to do this; the best option depends on things we don't know, at this point.

- You could pass `order_id` into the procedure, so you're only processing the `order_items` from a specific `order` each time through.
- If there's a date attached to `orders` or `order_items`, you could store the procedure's last run date, and only process orders with a date between the last run date and the current run date.
- If you have some control over the database structure, you could add a bit field to `order_items` to indicate whether it had been processed or not, and only process the unprocessed rows.
- Similarly, if the `items_new` records are retained as long as `order_items`, you could add `order_id` and `line_item_id` to `items_new`, and only insert records if there are no records with those two values already in the table.

NOTE: Working off dates could create a race condition, where a new order has been assigned its date, but hasn't actually been saved when the procedure runs - in that case, it might possibly be missed, and never have the ticket numbers generated.

UPDATE: - If you modify your procedure to accept 1 argument, `@proc_order_id`, which would be the `order_id` of the order you want to create ticket numbers for, then your cursor would be:

```
# Declare the cursor
DECLARE item_cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT oi.MerchID, m.MerchName, oi.quantity FROM orders o
        JOIN order_items oi ON o.id = oi.order_id
        JOIN merchandise m ON m.MerchID = oi.MerchID
            WHERE o.customer_id = 2 AND
            MerchCatID = '7' OR MerchCatID = '8' AND
            o.order_id = @proc_order_id;
```

On the other hand, if you add `order_id` and `line_item_id` to `items_new`, the cursor would be:

```
DECLARE item_cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT oi.MerchID, m.MerchName, o.order_id, oi.line_item_id, oi.quantity FROM orders o
        JOIN order_items oi ON o.id = oi.order_id
        JOIN merchandise m ON m.MerchID = oi.MerchID
            WHERE o.customer_id = 2 AND
            MerchCatID = '7' OR MerchCatID = '8' AND
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM items_new
                         WHERE order_id = o.order_id
                           AND line_item_id = oi.line_item_id);
```

Comment: so would it be like a `WHERE order_id = NEW.order_id?

Comment: Also the last solution is actually Genius in how simple of a solution it is. Thank you @RDFozz for all your help!

Comment: @Adam - Updated with code for cursor if you're passing the procedure an `order_id` parameter named `@proc_order_id`